# Reverse query in Django Many to Many

Tags: python, django

I have a problem in django reverse many to many. Basically, I think I am missing something that I couldn't understand properly yet.
I have these models and views.

models.py

```
class TheorySyllabus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    subject_duration = models.ManyToManyField(
        SubjectDuration, related_name='subject_durations')
    course_type = models.ForeignKey(
        CourseType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Theory Syllabus'


class TheoryCourse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='theory_courses')
    theory_syllabus = models.ForeignKey(
        TheorySyllabus, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    fiscal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    license = models.ForeignKey(
        License, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(
        blank=True, null=True, default='default.png')
    id_card = models.ForeignKey(
        IDCard, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cap = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name
```

views.py

```
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = TheoryCourse
    queryset = TheoryCourse.objects.filter(
        is_active=True).order_by('-created_at')
    template_name = 'theory/course_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'theory_courses'
    paginate_by = 10
```

template

```
<div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
          <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Course Type</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for course in theory_courses %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{course.theory_syllabus.name}}</td>
                <td>{{course.name}}</td>
              </tr> 
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

What I need to do, is to retrieve the total number of students that are in each TheoryCourse model. But I really have no idea how to use the reverse relationship.
I tried to use that in the template with something like:

```
{% for student in theory_courses.students.all %}
              
            {% endfor %}
```

But, it's not working. I read all the django documentation but either I didn't understand something or I am doing something wrong.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So, you have `student` in your model, not `students`. Thus for will look something like this

```
{% for student in theory_courses.student.all %}


{% endfor%}
```

Furthermore, if you want to get only count, you can just use

```
{% for student_count in theory_courses.student.count %}

{% endfor %}
```

P.S. That has nothing to do with reverse (`related_name`) in many to many. `related name` just means that you can access your `TheoryCourse` model from `Student` with `Student.theory_courses`

Comment: Yeah the s was a typo in my post. But the problem is that this code is not working either. I think I am missing something on the reverse relationship

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Is it throwing or just shows nothing?

Comment: It doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you check if your view filters for at least 1 instance. If template has wrong syntax it raises `TemplateSyntaxError`, so maybe you are iterating over empty set?

Comment: Actually the instance has one item with 3 students inside. In the other forloop the instance is working properly, showing the course name and the theory_syllabus name.